# How to create own openauth and openid provider in asp.net mvc 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, openid

I'm using asp.net identity to implementing authentication in my sites, now, because in my business i have more than one site, i want to create an openid or OAuth service in my base site, which lets to our consumers to log in our each sites with one account.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You allow the users to sign in into Base site and then a cookie gets created which will be used by other sites to login.

More info on the following link. 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6586/Single-sign-on-across-multiple-applications-in-ASPq

Comment: Cool, but i have not using forms authentication. and each of my sites is an independent site.

Comment: Even of you use cookies and owin cookies authentication middleware, this Will work. I have worked on this.

Comment: Just set the name in sync between the sites, the machine key and framework compatibility is also to be looked at